# Swift 3 - Difference between two arrays of dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, comparison

I have two arrays of dictionaries:

```
let arrayA = [["name1": "email1"], ["name2": "email2"]]
let arrayB = [["name1": "email1"], ["name3": "email3"]]
```

I want to compare them and get another two arrays: arrayC should have the elements in arrayA but not in arrayB, and arrayD should have the elements in arrayB but not in arrayA:

```
let arrayC = [["name2": "email2"]]
let arrayD = [["name3": "email3"]]
```

How can I do this taking into the consideration large arrays?

Answer (score 13):

Here you go

```
let arrayA = [["name1": "email1"], ["name2": "email2"]]
let arrayB = [["name1": "email1"], ["name3": "email3"]]

let arrayC = arrayA.filter{
    let dict = $0
    return !arrayB.contains{ dict == $0 }
}

let arrayD = arrayB.filter{
    let dict = $0
    return !arrayA.contains{ dict == $0 }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this answer may be complicating things and that you can use filter but...have you considered using `Sets` instead of `Arrays`?

Sets can give you operations for finding elements in `setA` but not in `setB` or elements in `setA` and `setB` out of the box.

There are a few caveats about sets though. As it says in [The Swift Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

> A set stores distinct values of the same type in a collection with no defined ordering. You can use a set instead of an array when the order of items is not important, or when you need to ensure that an item only appears once.

notice from the above:

- Distinct: Meaning no duplicates
- No definded ordering: Means that you cannot expect your sets to be in order

Also, notice this (also from The Swift Programming Guide):

> A type must be hashable in order to be stored in a set—that is, the type must provide a way to compute a hash value for itself.

If you can live with that...then sets are a fine solution I think.

Here is an example...I created a simple `Email` struct and made that implement `Hashable`:

```
struct Email {
    let name: String
    let email: String
}

extension Email: Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return "\(name)\(email)".hashValue
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Email, rhs: Email) -> Bool {
         return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.email == rhs.email
    }
}
```

And that can then be used like so:

```
let arrayA = [Email(name: "name1", email: "email1"), Email(name: "name2", email: "email2")]
let arrayB = [Email(name: "name1", email: "email1"), Email(name: "name3", email: "email3")]
let setA = Set(arrayA)
let setB = Set(arrayB)

let inBothAAndB = setA.intersection(setB) //gives me an Email with "name1", "email1"
let inAButNotB = setA.subtracting(setB) //gives me an Email with "name2", "email2"
let inBButNotA = setB.subtracting(setA) //gives me an Email with "name3", "email3"
```

So...I don't know if that confuses things for you or makes things harder or maybe impossible (if you're data can contain more than one element with the same name and email for instance) but...I just thought you should consider sets :)

Hope that helps you.